# Jenkins: Git Polling stopped working for only one job

Tags: jenkins, polling

I have Git Poll SCM set to every minute ( * * * * *). It stopped working a couple of days ago.

Based on the Git Polling Logs: Started on Jun 9, 2022 7:31:00 PM

It seems to be working on other jobs fine. Already checked the logs and don't see any issue.

I can build the job manually and it builds all those new SCM changes.

Any idea why?

Comment: What about the logs on the Git server? (Is the polling using ssh, or https? Inspect either the sshd logs, or the https server logs.) Note that Git itself is not involved at all here: this is all on Jenkins and anything Jenkins is running, since a manual build is working. (That is, you've ruled out all the possible Git-side problems.)

Comment: When you say "job".. what type?  Pipeline, freestyle project, etc?  Also what Jenkins..  I could give you some files to look at but just try to delete and recreate the job